# tornado-redis: Why the 'listen' and the 'brpop' of tornado-redis can't work at the same time

Tags: python, redis, tornado, coroutine

The code like this:

```
from tornadoredis import Client
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.gen import coroutine, Task

rds = Client()

@coroutine
def listen_pub():
    def handle(msg):
        print msg

    yield Task(rds.subscribe, channels='pub')
    rds.listen(handle)


@coroutine
def listen_list():
    while True:
        res = yield Task(rds.brpop, keys='list')
        print res


def test():
    listen_pub()
    listen_list()

test()
IOLoop.current().start()
```

When I running the code above, only 'listen_list' can receive messages.
Why the 'listen_list' doesn't work?
How can I listen the message from LIST and PUB/SUB at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the redis documentation:

> A client subscribed to one or more channels ***should not issue
>   commands***, although it can subscribe and unsubscribe to and from
>   other channels. The reply of the SUBSCRIBE and UNSUBSCRIBE operations
>   are sent in the form of messages, so that the client can just read a
>   coherent stream of messages where the first element indicates the type
>   of message.

You have to use two connection clients.
Source: http://redis.io/topics/pubsub